# Short way for declaring private variables

Tags: c++, default, openmp, shortcut

In my code, I have lots of private variables but only a few shared ones. So I had to write all private variables in private clause one by one. `default` does not help because it only provides two choices: `none` and `shared`. As a result, is there a way to make private as default?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Just for `private`? :)

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP does not provide `default(private)` for C++ for the simple reason that C++ already provides a mechanism to make those variables private - just *define them in the inner scope*:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   int this_one_is_private;
   double this_on_is_private_too;
   int and_this_one_too;
   double more_privateness;
   ...
}
```

OpenMP does have `DEFAULT(PRIVATE)` for Fortran since the latter doesn't have mechanisms to define variables in the inner scope.